# Diagnosing slow response times for AWS Application Load Balancers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

I am working on a POC for an application that uses CloudFront, ALB and Fargate. While I have been developing the application I noticed that the ALB sometimes has slow response times. I came across the following thread on the AWS forum. It is from 8 years ago, but I thought it might explain some of the behavior I am seeing:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=102879

> The reason for the delay is because you have the ELB setup for multi-az without any application instances in the other 2 AZ's configured. Without instances in those AZ's requests will tend to fail because the ELb still returns IP addresses for those AZ's even if there are no active application instances. Please disable the other AZ's for now and continue your tests.

I have a similar setup. 2 AZs and only one Fargate task in my backend API Fargate service that the load balancer sends traffic to.

Here's what I get running `dig` against the ALB DNSName (ALB DNSName and IP addresses have been changed):

```
dig my-alb-123.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.12-Ubuntu <<>> my-alb-123.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 52135
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;my-alb-123.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. IN A

my-alb-123.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 60 IN A 51.4.143.123
my-alb-123.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 60 IN A 33.553.34.153

;; Query time: 3113 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Tue May 26
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 124
```

Running this again, I get the same result, but with a `Query time` of `0msec`. Runnging this dozens of time, I see that most results return `0msec`, and some that are ~3000msec.

For a staging environment, should I use one AZ?

Comment: Hi, have you enabled cross-zone load balancing?

Comment: If cross-zone load balancing was off, it would explain why some connections fail. If it is ON, then all requests would receive a response but some might be _slightly_ slower (but this would not account for 3 second delays). I'd be more suspicious of the 3 seconds taken to resolve a DNS Name (shown in the `dig` listing above). The `0msec` response is probably while the response is cached. Therefore, try to find where in the DNS resolution chain all this time is being consumed. For example, point your DNS to `8.8.8.8` and see whether it resolves consistently faster.

Comment: @mokugo-devops I checked the docs about cross-zone load balancing and I found that "With Application Load Balancers, cross-zone load balancing is always enabled."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Query time: 3113 msec

This is way too much. I **checked on my 2-AZ ALB**, and the times I am  getting are about **60 msec**, also in `us-east-1`:

```
dig xxxxx.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com

; <<>> DiG 9.16.2 <<>> xxxxx.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 56978
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;xxxx.elb.amazonaws.com.    IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
xxxxx.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.  60 IN A 52.0.195.xx
xxxxx.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.  60 IN A 50.19.163.xx

;; Query time: 53 msec
;; SERVER: 10.1.1.1#53(10.1.1.1)
;; WHEN: Wed May 27 16:08:53 AWST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 123
```

The times reported by dig are related to ALB's DNS resolution. And the two IPs shown are **ALB nodes** (one in each AZ). They do not depend on whether you have Fargate or EC2 instances.

> For a staging environment, should I use one AZ?

If your Fargate service is set to only one AZ, any requests that will come to a node of ALB in a second zone, will have to be routed to the first zone anyway. There does not seem to be much benefit of having ALB in two AZs, but Fargate service limited to only one AZ.